# Weird Core Data Reaction - Not Detecting NSManagedObject Sub Classes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

There seems to be a very weird bug in my app in which I'm using `Core Data`.

I handled everything required already, and **it was working for like past recent weeks.**

I closed the project yesterday, and started development today ( **with no modifications in code** ) and now every time I wanna add a row to my database, I get an exception saying the following class is not a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, which I'm ridiculously sure is not true, first because it was working for days, and second because I generated them automatically as `NSManagedObject` subclasses. I tried regenerating classes using `Editor->Create NSManagedObject Subclasses` in my data model, but it didn't help me at all.

It's really weird that I get this exception out of blue and all of a sudden WITHOUT EVEN A LINE OF MODIFICATION in my code :(

Anybody got any idea ? I really appreciate any help.
Thanks

BTW, Here're some code that may help :

**The Error :**

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '"Message" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject.`

**Message Class Header File (Auto-Generated) :**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class File;

@interface Message : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * data;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * fileId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * number;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * status;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * xmppId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) File *contains;

@end
```

**The method in which I try to create a new message object :**

```
+ (void)sendXMPPMessage:(NSString *)messageStr containingFile:(NSData *)fileData toNumber:(NSString *)number
{
    if(fileData == nil)
    {
        NSString *newID = [self generateNewXMPPMessageID];

        SunBirdAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SunBirdAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate sendXMPPMessage:messageStr withID:newID toNumber:number];

        NSMutableDictionary *messageDataDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        [messageDataDic setObject:messageStr forKey:@"body"];
        [messageDataDic setObject:@"Outgoing" forKey:@"type"];
        [messageDataDic setObject:newID forKey:@"xmppId"];
        [messageDataDic setObject:@"Sending" forKey:@"status"];
        [messageDataDic setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];
        [messageDataDic setObject:number forKey:@"number"];

        [Message messageWithMessageInfo:messageDataDic inManagedObjectContext:[appDelegate managedObjectContext]];
    }
    else
    {
        //Handle Database With File Data
    }
}
```

**Creating a New Message Object -> The Create Category On Message Class (Message+Create.m)** :

```
+ (Message *)messageWithMessageInfo:(NSDictionary *)messageInfo inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    SunBirdAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SunBirdAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    Message *newMessage = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Message"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"xmppId = %@", [messageInfo objectForKey:@"msgId"]];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"xmppId" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!matches || ([matches count] > 1))
    {
        // handle error
    }
    else if ([matches count] == 0)
    {
        newMessage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Message" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        newMessage.data = [messageInfo objectForKey:@"body"];
        newMessage.type = [messageInfo objectForKey:@"type"];
        newMessage.date = [messageInfo objectForKey:@"date"];
        newMessage.xmppId = [messageInfo objectForKey:@"xmppId"];
        newMessage.status = [messageInfo objectForKey:@"status"];
        newMessage.number = [messageInfo objectForKey:@"number"];

        if ( [[messageInfo allKeys] containsObject:@"fileId"] )
        {
            newMessage.fileId = [messageInfo objectForKey:@"fileId"];
            newMessage.contains = [messageInfo objectForKey:@"fileData"];
        }
        else
        {
            newMessage.fileId = NULL;
            newMessage.contains = NULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        newMessage = [matches lastObject];
        NSLog(@"WARNING : NO NEW MESSAGE STORED IN DB ! MESSAGE WITH SAME XMPPID RETURNED");
    }
    [appDelegate saveContext];
    return newMessage;
}
```

And this is the line on which I'm being informed `Message` is not a subclass of `NSManagedObject` :

`newMessage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Message" inManagedObjectContext:context];`

Comment: try changing the class name from `Message` to something else ...

Comment: Why ? `Message` name was working perfectly

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and cleaning build folder? Reset content and Re-install on device? Have you changed Core Data model version?

Comment: Yeah, cleaning, reinstalling and resetting didn't help.
I renamed `Message`. Apparently it's a keyword that sometimes causes run time problems !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug i stumbled on in a project I worked on.

`Message` cannot be used an an entity name ... why? ... Apple ... ???

Don't really know.

Rename to something else and this usually solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, According to first suggestion in comments on my question, I did that too. But it sucks. Wasted me 5 hours of time.

Comment: Just formulated it as an answer so if someone look at this at some point it would be clearer

Comment: It cannot be used as an entity name because some genius at Apple named a class "Message" without using a namespace prefix (such as "UI", "NS", "AB", etc). **Make sure to open a bug report with Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com.**